# Why does the DeepSpeed `estimate_zero2_model_states_mem_needs_…` API report the same memory per CPU with different `offload_optimizer` option values?

Tags: gpu, cpu, deepspeed

The example provided in [Memory Requirements - DeepSpeed 0.10.1 documentation](https://deepspeed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/memory.html) is as follows:

```
python -c 'from deepspeed.runtime.zero.stage_1_and_2 import estimate_zero2_model_states_mem_needs_all_cold; \
estimate_zero2_model_states_mem_needs_all_cold(total_params=2851e6, num_gpus_per_node=8, num_nodes=1)'
```

```
Estimated memory needed for params, optim states and gradients for a:
HW: Setup with 1 node, 8 GPUs per node.
SW: Model with 2851M total params.
  per CPU  |  per GPU |   Options
  127.45GB |   5.31GB | offload_optimizer=cpu
  127.45GB |  15.93GB | offload_optimizer=none
```

I noticed that the `per CPU` value is the same for both lines.
However, `offload_optimizer` takes values of `cpu` and `none` respectively, where the `cpu` option value theoretically would store the optimizer state and gradient on the CPU, thus taking up more CPU memory, which doesn't match the API report.
Am I misunderstanding the implementation of the ZeRO2 or DeepSpeed `offload_optimizer` parameter?

I reproduced the example on my own machine.